# Is there a way to validate ruby syntax on save in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby, textmate, sublimetext

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?  It was pretty easy to find in TextMate, but so far no luck for Sublime 2 (which I much prefer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeLinter) . I'm using it for Python, but it supports Ruby too.

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

Answer (score 3):

A Sublime Text 2 plugin which validates Ruby syntax (though it's not its core feature) is [RubyTest](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests), with the `Alt-Shift-V` keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used TextMate so I'm not sure how they accomplish it however you could either write a plugin for sublime text 2 to accomplish this. It's pretty easy to write a plugin in Sublime Text 2 and the site has some good documentation.

I however use Guard ( https://github.com/guard/guard ) and have it fire off events when a file is saved. Usually I'm using rspec, cucumber or both and have it run the tests against that specific file, you could have it run "ruby -c your_file.rb" which checks the syntax. Good benefit of this is you can have it setup growl notifications.

It does sound like a plugin is your best bet however.

David

Comment: That's actually a good idea.  The plugins for sublime are built around python, which I am unfamiliar with.  The growl/guard idea I think I can make work though.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple [RubyCheckOnSave](https://github.com/edgar/RubyCheckOnSave) plugin for Sublime Text 2, the plugin checks the syntax of ruby files when they're saved.

Try and let me know